# Edit specific line at specific position in Text file in Python

Tags: python

I have two variables **x1=123.12 and y1=123.45** which holds user entered values .Now I have a text file in which I have to change current **245.42 and 130.32** with the variable **x1 and y1** which holds user entered values.So **how can I modify text file** in python?

```
#text file:

var char12
name andy jordan
home illino

w1 345 3456 
p1 346 2123
addmoney 245.42
netmoney 130.32
```

Comment: Will the text preceding these values always be `addmoney` and `netmoney`?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: its a sudo file its just two words there are many more I just want to clear about concept so I given this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open the existing file and read the lines. Assuming that you want to replace the values that always follow 'addmoney' and 'netmoney', you can locate those lines and use `re.sub()` to substitute the values into those lines. Keep in mind that you can't simply overwrite text files in-place, so you store the modified lines and then recreate a new file at the end, like so:

```
x1 = 123.12
y1 = 123.45

import re

with open('mytextfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i, l in enumerate(lines):

        if l.startswith('addmoney'):
            lines[i] = re.sub(r'[0-9.]+', str(x1), lines[i])
        elif l.startswith('netmoney'):
            lines[i] = re.sub(r'[0-9.]+', str(y1), lines[i])

out = open('modifiedtextfile.txt', 'w'); out.writelines(lines); out.close()
```

Comment: thanks for code @rahlf23  now I cleared about the concept.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the green chark mark to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If i want to overwrite same file I have to use same file name in this Is it right?out = open('mytextfile.txt', 'w');out.writelines(lines); out.close()     @rahlf23

Comment: Could you explain me a meaning of this line->  lines[i] = re.sub(r'[0-9.]+', str(x1), lines[i])   rest of things I understood. @rahlf23

Comment: This part `r'[0-9.]+'` simply means to search for any numbers from `0-9`, as well as any literal `.` and the `+` indicates to match at least one to unlimited of those characters. Look at the docs for `re.sub()` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: And what if that **addmoney and netmoney**   starts  in the middle of the line ? @rahlf23